# making curl request to google oauth api

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to do the following curl request:

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=$access_token";

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
if (!empty($headers)) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$resp = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $resp; //prints 'Not found'
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $httpCode; //prints '404'
curl_close($ch);
```

first `echo` prints 'Not found', second prints '404'. Still, if I do `echo "$url?$params"`, and copy outputed url to adress bar of browser, the page will open. Have no idea what can cause `Not found` on correct url. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

**UPD.** here's dump of `curl_getinfo()`:

```
array(20) { ["url"]=> string(45) "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"
["content_type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8" ["http_code"]=> int(404)
["header_size"]=> int(360) ["request_size"]=> int(218) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=>
float(0.657275) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.00257) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.162467)
["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.495426) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> 
float(9) ["speed_download"]=> float(13) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
["download_content_length"]=> float(0) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(0)
["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.657247) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) }
```

Comment: Are you sure you've added a question mark at the end of $url in your code?

Comment: Show us all info from curl_getinfo. By the way, in your browser you use GET and in the code above you use POST.

Comment: @Nin,thank you for answer. Updated the question. `$curl_post` if `false`, I'm doing GET request

Comment: If you're doing a GET, you should add the $params to you're url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo";
    $params = "access_token=$access_token";

    $ch = curl_init($url . '?' . $params);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    if (!empty($headers)) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


    $resp = curl_exec($ch); 
    echo $resp; //prints 'Not found'
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo $httpCode; //prints '404'
    curl_close($ch);
```

Now you're sending using GET and you ignore the SSL cert.